# What does the model attribute of a view-state in spring webflow file contain?

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

I am a beginner to spring webflow. I see that the model view binding is done in the view-state tag using     model attribute of the     view-state.

I would like to know how to give values to this attribute     model.

is it like-

```
<view-state id = "somePage" model = "classname">
```

So is it that model attribute is assigned to a classname in lowercase? or should it be a bean defined in any of the xml files? May I be suggested how to assign value to the     model attribute?

Comment: Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

you might want to read the entire spring doc on webflow.
 it has nothing to do with a class, it's an instance of an object that you plan on POSTing (in your view). That object has to be serializable, and it has to be instantiated (from an input, set, result of evaluate, etc.)
[here is the section about model](https://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/reference/#_view_model)